# Vimeo API. Trouble with SetVolume method

Tags: javascript, api, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm using Vimeo api in my project, but I have a problem with volume setting.
If I do so:

```
// Create the player
var player = new Vimeo.Player('video2', options);

//Ready event
player.ready().then(function() {
  player.play();  
});
```

Everything works, but without sound.
However, if I do so:

```
// Create the player
var player = new Vimeo.Player('video2', options);

//Ready event
player.ready().then(function() {
  player.play();  
  player.setVolume(0.5);
});
```

The video does not play, and the screen hangs his screensaver.
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially by calling play when the video is ready, you are attempting to autoplay. However, this volume problem occurs because browsers no longer allow autoplay with sound (especially [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)). You can read more about this on our [Help article](https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004485728-Autoplaying-and-looping-embedded-videos) as well.

Therefore, it is impossible to programmatically play a video with volume without a user clicking/interacting with the video first.  Only afterwards will a call to setVolume work.